# Mediawiki, problems with Parsoids

Tags: php, mediawiki, parsoid

I'm getting this error message in Mediawiki, any hint ?

```
{"message":"Error: exception of type TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wt2Html\\TT\\ListHandler::pushList() must be an instance of stdClass, instance of Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\NodeData\\DataParsoid given, called in vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wt2Html/TT/ListHandler.php on line 518","exception":
{"id":"8be3b0fb2f42e48816771d33","type":"TypeError","file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wt2Html/TT/ListHandler.php","line":304,"message":"Argument 2 passed to Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wt2Html\\TT\\ListHandler::pushList() must be an instance of stdClass, instance of Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\NodeData\\DataParsoid given, called in vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wt2Html/TT/ListHandler.php on line 518","code":0,"url":"/rest.php/www.tematichedigenere.com/v3/page/html/Cosa_c%27%C3%A8_da_fare%3F/27246?redirect=false&stash=true","caught_by":"other","backtrace":[
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wt2Html/TT/ListHandler.php","line":518,"function":"pushList","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wt2Html\\TT\\ListHandler","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wt2Html/TT/ListHandler.php","line":269,"function":"doListItem","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wt2Html\\TT\\ListHandler","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wt2Html/TT/ListHandler.php","line":85,"function":"onListItem","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wt2Html\\TT\\ListHandler","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wt2Html/TT/TokenHandler.php","line":150,"function":"onTag","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wt2Html\\TT\\ListHandler","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wt2Html/TokenTransformManager.php","line":132,"function":"process","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wt2Html\\TT\\TokenHandler","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wt2Html/TokenTransformManager.php","line":195,"function":"processChunk","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wt2Html\\TokenTransformManager","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wt2Html/TreeBuilder/TreeBuilderStage.php","line":487,"function":"processChunkily","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wt2Html\\TokenTransformManager","type":"->"},
{"function":"processChunkily","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wt2Html\\TreeBuilder\\TreeBuilderStage","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wt2Html/DOMPostProcessor.php","line":903,"function":"current","class":"Generator","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wt2Html/ParserPipeline.php","line":180,"function":"processChunkily","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wt2Html\\DOMPostProcessor","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wt2Html/ParserPipelineFactory.php","line":308,"function":"parseChunkily","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wt2Html\\ParserPipeline","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Wikitext/ContentModelHandler.php","line":123,"function":"parse","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wt2Html\\ParserPipelineFactory","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Parsoid.php","line":172,"function":"toDOM","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Wikitext\\ContentModelHandler","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/src/Parsoid.php","line":210,"function":"parseWikitext","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Parsoid","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/extension/src/Rest/Handler/ParsoidHandler.php","line":587,"function":"wikitext2html","class":"Wikimedia\\Parsoid\\Parsoid","type":"->"},
{"file":"vendor/wikimedia/parsoid/extension/src/Rest/Handler/PageHandler.php","line":88,"function":"wt2html","class":"MWParsoid\\Rest\\Handler\\ParsoidHandler","type":"->"},
{"file":"includes/Rest/Router.php","line":414,"function":"execute","class":"MWParsoid\\Rest\\Handler\\PageHandler","type":"->"},
{"file":"includes/Rest/Router.php","line":338,"function":"executeHandler","class":"MediaWiki\\Rest\\Router","type":"->"},
{"file":"includes/Rest/EntryPoint.php","line":168,"function":"execute","class":"MediaWiki\\Rest\\Router","type":"->"},
{"file":"includes/Rest/EntryPoint.php","line":133,"function":"execute","class":"MediaWiki\\Rest\\EntryPoint","type":"->"},
{"file":"rest.php","line":31,"function":"main","class":"MediaWiki\\Rest\\EntryPoint","type":"::"}]},"httpCode":500,"httpReason":"Internal Server Error"}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [MediaWiki, trying to investigate VisualEditor "Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server (HTTP 500)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73238686/mediawiki-trying-to-investigate-visualeditor-error-contacting-the-parsoid-rest)? Like I said there, probably a version incompatibility issue - Parsoid is managed via Composer, make sure it is up to date.

Comment: @Tgr: I've checked the version from Special:Version but it's "-", I've tried to download mediawiki 1.38.2 and compare to the server version, Parsoid folder is exactly aligned to fresh download.

Comment: @Tgr: a point that I can't clearly get is why composer update on server creates a vendor subfolder inside every folder. Executing composer update on server is a good idea? https://i.imgur.com/vPudVZg.png

Comment: Solved. I simply had to delete the folder /vendor/wikimedia/parsoid and copy it from scratch. I couldn't see there were issues because of a problem in the compare tool. I got help in the IRC channel.

Comment: It shouldn't create subfolders. No idea why that's happening to you. Running Composer on the server should work fine in theory.